# Cannot find output folder for .exe file using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am completely new to python and trying to create an application (or .exe) file for python using pyinstaller. I ran the command pyinstaller -[DIRECTORY].py and it saved it to an output directory "C:\Windows\System32\Dist\Foo", however when i tried to locate the directory it did not seem to exist (Dist). 
NOTE: i'm trying to convert a .py file to .exe file in Python 3.5
Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2):

If you set your command directory to the `.py` script location and run `pyinstaller yourscript.py`, it will generate folders in the same location as your script. The folder named `dist/` will contain the .exe file.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try easily the command:

```
`pyinstaller yourscript.py`
```

You will get your output folder anyway if everything is correct with your software/module.

Second you can have no rights into System32 folder, so you could try a different folder.

Third you might have inconsistency with the path \ or /.

Hope those three suggestions will lead you to the correct solution :-)
Have a nice day.